# Error al convertir el valor del parametro de string a Int32 - VB C# y SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, vb

Tengo un aplicativo que me llena un DataDridview desde un Procedimiento almacenado, en el cual en un textbox coloco el parametro y luego en un boton le doy click para que execute el SP y , muestre todo en el Data

sin embargo me genera este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo en C# dentro del boton

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;


namespace Aplicativo_Cumplimiento
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Los argumentos de conexion a la base de datos
            string args = "Data Source=adsysdb;Initial Catalog=Cumplimiento;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = args;

            try
            {
                //Indico el SP que voy a utilizar
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("paGenerarArchivo_SSRU_RequerimientoUrgente", conn);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);



                //Envió los parámetros que necesito

             //   String valorconvertido ;
             //   valorconvertido = Convert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text);

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Identidad", SqlDbType.Int);
                param.Value = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();

                //Aquí ejecuto el SP y lo lleno en el DataTable
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                //Enlazo mis datos obtenidos en el DataTable con el grid
                dtgv.DataSource = dt;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btexportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\folder\UIFSSRU20220411.asc");
            for (int i = 0; i < dtgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dtgv.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.Write("\t" + dtgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                }
                writer.WriteLine("");
               // writer.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
            }
            writer.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
        }
    }
    }
```

Y el SP el parametro es **VARCHAR(20)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se cual pueda ser el error si alguien me ayuda

Comment: `SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Identidad", SqlDbType.Int)` Por qué tienes `SqlDbType.Int`, y en tu sp lo tienes como `varchar`? Por qué estás convirtiendo `textBox1.Text` que ya es `string a `string` -> `param.Value = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);`?

Comment: si, tendrias que convertirlo a int para que lo puedas enviar ya que indicas que es de tipo int y mandas un texto, pero tu sp recibe un varchar entonces SqlDbType.Int aqui tendrias que cambiarle

Comment: En efecto, he cambiado a **SqlDbType.NVarChar** y **param.Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();** y funciono perfecto